# buildozer apk crashes with import statement nest-asyncio

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I am building an apk using buildozer, I have included the necessary import statements in the buildozer spec requirements and ran adb logcat the app is crashing on Nomodule found for nest-asyncio even though it is included, I will include below the adb logcat error and main.py here.

```
import kivy
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
import ast
import datetime

import asyncio
#from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import aiofiles
#from kivy.app import async_runTouchApp
import nest_asyncio


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent

    def clear_canvas(self, obj):
        self.painter.canvas.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

> ###logcat error###
> 04-13 14:54:44.522 19120 19145 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
> 04-13 14:54:44.546 19120 19145 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
> 04-13 14:54:44.546 19120 19145 I python  :    File "/home/mat/Desktop/new39/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 14, in
>
> 04-13 14:54:44.546 19120 19145 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nest_asyncio'
> 04-13 14:54:44.546 19120 19145 I python  : Python for android ended.
> 04-13 14:54:44.634  1138  1138 I sensors-hal: batch:242, android.sensor.accelerometer/11, period=200000000, max_latency=0
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1138  1138 I sensors-hal: set_config:63, sample_period_ns is adjusted to 200000000 based on min/max delay_ns
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1750  3336 I ActivityManager: appDiedLocked: app=ProcessRecord{1ef0121 19120:org.test.myapp/u0a340}
> thread=android.os.BinderProxy@1cfb156 fromBinderDied=true
> isKilledByAm=false reason=null
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1750  3336 I ActivityManager: Process org.test.myapp (pid 19120) has died: fg  TOP
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1138  1138 I sensors-hal: send_sync_sensor_request:359, send sync request
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1750  6698 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{87fc8cd u0 org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1138  1138 I sensors-hal: send_sync_sensor_request:385, wait for notification of response
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1750  6698 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object '87fc8cd org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
> (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input
> manager!
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1043  1043 I Zygote  : Process 19120 exited cleanly (255)
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1750  2122 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10340 pid 19120 in 0ms
> 04-13 14:54:44.635  1138 18852 I sensors-hal: ssc_conn_resp_cb:666, resp_value = 0
> 04-13 14:54:44.636  1138  1138 I sensors-hal: send_sync_sensor_request:391, takes 0 ms to receive the response with
> 0
> 04-13 14:54:44.636  1138  1138 I sensors-hal: batch:251, android.sensor.accelerometer/11, period=200000000, max_latency=0
> request completed
> 04-13 14:54:44.639  1750  6698 V WindowManager: Changing focus of displayId=0 to null from Window{87fc8cd u0
> org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
> 04-13 14:54:44.641  1750  3336 W ActivityTaskManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{51f499c u0
> org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2053}: app died, no
> saved state

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem and it turned out to be extremely simple, every buildozer spec I found online had "nest-asyncio" in the requirements all I did was change that to "nest_asyncio" and it worked. So painfully simple it seems to work on python 3.9 not on 3.6